# Filtering multiple variables from one column

Tags: r, filter, subset

I have a question to which I can't find an answer on this forum. I have been trying to filter a column from my data set in R. I am using a data set with 7321 rows and 28 columns. One column, which is about the type of businesses, has four different variables: Wirtschaft, Hochschule, außeruniversitäre Forschung and Sonstige. I would like to combine Wirtschaft and außeruniversitäre Forschung in a new column called private, and filter the Hochschule variable into a new column called public. 
Now, I have tried the following:

First I tried creating a subset in which both 'private variables' are included:

```
subdataprivate <- subset(data, typ == "außeruniversitäre Forschung" & typ == "Wirtschaft")
```

The problem here is, that I get a subset with 0 observations for 28 variables. When I run the codes seperately, like this:

```
subdataprivate1 <- subset(data, typ == "außeruniversitäre Forschung")

subdataprivate2 <- subset(data, typ == "Wirtschaft")
```

I do get sufficient observations for all variables (1559 observations of 28 variables and 3548 observations of 28 variables). The thing is, that I need to have these types of businesses combined to run my analyses.

The same problem occurs when I try filtering the data using the dplyr package. 
Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I'm rather new to R and this forum, so I apologise in advance for my layman-way of asking this question.

Comment: Perhaps change the `&` to `|` to represent OR instead of AND?

Comment: Use `%in%`: `subdataprivate=subset(data, typ %in% c("außeruniversitäre Forschung", "Wirtschaft"))`

Comment: another option is to use `grepl`, so the code would be `subdataprivate=subset(data, grepl("^außeruniversitäre Forschung$|^Wirtschaft$", typ, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE))`

Comment: `typ == "this" AND typ == "that"` is always `FALSE`. If you want any of two or more alternatives, use `%in%` like @markus wrote.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you all for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Without posting your data I have to use dummy data, but I'd do something like this using `mutate` and `if_else`.  Once you have this column you can then use subsetting like you have with base R or use `filter` from `dplyr`.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(school = rep(c("school 1", "school 2", "school 3", "school 4"), 5))

data_transformed <- data %>%
 mutate(private_public = if_else(school == "school 1" | school == "school 2",
                                 "private",
                                 "public"))
```